# javascript functions arguments in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

what I'm trying to do is this

```
    $.each($(".canvas"), function(n) {
        var canvas = $(this)[0].getContext("2d");     
        canvas.drawImage(options[n]);
    });
```

where options would be an array of arguments, but can't figure out how should the array be formatted for it to work

obviously not

```
['img, 0,  0, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17', 'img, 0,  0, 80, 12, 21, 16, 70, 17']
```

this neither

```
[''+img+', 0,  0, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17', ''+img+', 0,  0, 80, 12, 21, 16, 70, 17']
```

nor this

```
{0: [img, 0,  0, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17]}
```

this would not work either

```
var options = [[img, 0,  0, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17],
               [img, 0, 16, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17],
               [img, 0, 32, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17],
               [img, 0, 48, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17]];

img.onload = function() {
    $.each($(".canvas"), function(n) {
        var canvas = $(this)[0].getContext("2d");     
        canvas.drawImage(options[n].join(', '));
    });
};
```

the error is alway Uncaught TypeError: Type error or Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: `drawImage` takes several arguments, not just one which is a string. `foo(a, b)` is different than `foo('a, b')`. Only because there a commas in the string does not make it a list of arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply).

```
canvas.drawImage.apply(canvas, options[n]);
```

Where `options[n]` looks something like

```
[img, 0, 0, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17]
```

---

Full example:

```
var options = [[img, 0,  0, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17],
               [img, 0, 16, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17],
               [img, 0, 32, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17],
               [img, 0, 48, 70, 17, 21, 16, 70, 17]];

$(img).load(function()
{
    $(".canvas").each(function(n)
    {
        var canvas = this.getContext('2d');     
        canvas.drawImage.apply(canvas, options[n]);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/5EQbC/

Comment: `options` has to have the right structure though. And `img` must be a DOM element afaik.

Comment: @foxx: You have to use  `canvas.drawImage.apply(canvas, options[n]);` (pass `canvas` as first argument).

Comment: lovely, did try apply() before, but with this instead of canvas, stupid me, thanks